# Convert text into html javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html content with special characters

```
&lt;div class=&quot;agfMailBodyHtml&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;Test mail 5 - reply op rich text with &lt;b&gt;attachements\r\n&lt;/b&gt;also with &lt;b&gt;attchements&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=1 color=#5f5f5f face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;
```

is it possible to convert it into html using javascript?

Comment: Do you mean add it to the document?

Comment: yes, the data i am getting from mid-tier is in the above format. i need to convert it to html

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/unescape-html-in-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible:

```
var str = "&lt;div class=&quot;agfMailBodyHtml&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;Test mail 5 - reply op rich text with &lt;b&gt;attachements\r\n&lt;/b&gt;also with &lt;b&gt;attchements&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=1 color=#5f5f5f face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;";

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;

div.innerHTML = div.textContent;
alert(div.innerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P7BJP/1/)

Comment: Can you please explain your code? Why are we setting the innerHTML twice with the same value?

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = "&lt;div class=&quot;agfMailBodyHtml&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;Test mail 5 - reply op rich text with &lt;b&gt;attachements\r\n&lt;/b&gt;also with &lt;b&gt;attchements&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=2 face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;/font&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;br&gt;&lt;font size=1 color=#5f5f5f face=&quot;sans-serif&quot;&gt;";
var html = el.textContent;
```